# is IPFS bizantine fault tolerant?

Tags: blockchain, ipfs

It seems that IPFS is not BFT (Bizantine fault). Am I wrong ?
Maybe there are some project that provide such a feature on top of IPFS.
Or am I constrained to use a DLT (distributed ledger technology) with IPFS to get this feature ?

best

JG

Comment: A spin on that question might be whether and how IPFS DHT tries to protect the users from Sybil Attacks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure the question makes sense.

IPFS is not a blockchain that tries to achieve some kind of consensus. IPFS/libp2p provides infrastructure on which you could build blockchains such as filecoin or others, which like most public blockchains tries to achieve byzantine fault tolerance.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify in more detail IPFS is a protocol for storing, asking, and receiving files. Because the filename is a sha256 of its contents I do not have to trust that you haven't tampered with the file when I receive it because I can just hash and verify.

BFT is about reaching consensus due to partial failure or attack. Receiving a file and confirming it is tamper-free is binary yes or no by a single node. No BFT is requried.